# Start Netbeans with specified jdkhome

Tags: netbeans

I want to specify the JDK to run NetBeans on. I have the shortcut of Netbeans on the desktop and have this as the target:

```
"D:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3 Beta\bin\netbeans64.exe" --jdkhome "e:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05"
```

However, it doesn't work and it still look for JDK in the folder `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05`, which was specified in the file `netbeans.conf` located in the `etc` folder.

I don't want to change this `netbeans.conf` file, and want to specify the jdk using the shortcut. What did I do wrong?

Comment: [Seems to be the way to do it](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJdkHome). Are you sure the path to the JDK's correct?

Comment: yes I'm sure, if I change it directly in the `netbeans.conf` file it works without problem